# Canonical Quantization in QFT in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, field-theory, quantum-gravity, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a scalar field propagating on some curved background $g_{\mu\nu}$, satisfying the field equation
\begin{equation}
D[\varphi] = 0
\end{equation}
where $D$ is some differential operator. Is there some known prescription to quantizing this theory? From what I have seen, the standard books on QFT in curved spacetime treat only the case where the above field equation is the standard Klein-Gordon equation, so that they can define the inner product
$$
(\phi_1, \phi_2) = -i \int_{\Sigma} \phi_1 \overleftrightarrow{\partial} \phi_2^* \sqrt{-g} d\Sigma_{\mu}
$$
I guess what I am wondering is how can one obtain such an inner product for a general equation of motion that is not the Klein-Gordon one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This post (v1) seems _too broad._

Comment: You cannot quantize "this theory" because $D[\varphi]=0$ is not a "theory". In order to specify a theory, you need more information. What are the phase-space variables? what are the constraints? what type of field (Lorentz/Grassmann/etc.) is $\varphi$? What are the boundary conditions? etc. A well-posed action principle essentially answers all these questions, and more, and so it does constitute "a theory". An equation alone does not.

Comment: ... but anyway, if you only want the bracket, there is in fact a generic prescription (that goes under the name of *Peierls bracket*, and is constructed out of the Wronskian of $D$). See De Witt's *A Global Approach to QFT* for the precise definition.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.